# jquery drag and drop: Can I prevent an element to be dropped to another div after it has been dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get this work for a long time and without any luck, I decided to ask here.

I am creating drag and drop divs using jquery ui library.

Currently, I have many divs with class 'parent' that I add dynamically on the page:

```
$( ".parent" ).droppable({
        accept: ".child",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    tolerance:'touch',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" ).appendTo(ui.Target);
        }
    });
```

I then create a div on the fly with class 'child' and the child div can be dragged and dropped into any of the parent divs.  Please note that for the parent droppables, tolerance is set to 'touch'

```
$( ".child" ).draggable();
```

Parent divs are smaller in size than the child div.
Whenever I drag a child div and if I move it over two parent divs (please note that at this point, I haven't dropped the child div), ideally, I want the child div to be dropped only into the first parent div.

What happens is that the child div is appended into the first parent div.  Then it is moved from the 1st parent div into the second parent div.

Is there a way to allow child div to remain draggable but only be dropped into the first parent div?

Thanks for reading.

If it is not clear, please let me know and I will rephrase it

Dragging the child over parent 2 and 3 shows the same behaviour:
[http://jsfiddle.net/Dyawa/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/Dyawa/5/)

Comment: This would be a lot easier to understand if there was a jsFiddle to go along with it.

Comment: So, you want the child div to be dropped to the first div you hover above (even when you drop it on the second one)?

Comment: yes, imagine child div is x3 in size and i can hover it over parent div 1 and parent div 2 (so both divs can accept it) but when i drop it then i want it to only be dropped into the first parent div (not the second one).  Right now, child div enters parent div 1 and then it enters parent div 2.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dyawa/ - please update this to show what you mean...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dyawa/3/  if you drag child over parent 2 and 3, you will see the effect

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dyawa/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you took the point of noting it is set to:

```
tolerance:'touch'
```

But this is exactly what this means - 'Draggable overlaps the droppable any amount.' (from http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance)

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Dyawa/2/ - see the difference just by removing the tolerance.

Suggest you use:

```
tolerance: 'pointer'
```

Comment: the problem is that the child box can't 100% fit into the parent (sometimes because of awkward positioning), that's why i chose it to be 'touch' so it can go in

Comment: but intersect only needs 50% - not 100%, is that not enough? Can you provide a fiddle that illustrates your intent?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dyawa/5/  this explains what i am trying to say, try to insert child into parent 1 (i've removed touch)

Comment: i was trying pointer now too. seems like pointer does the trick.  it's not the best solution because it expects mouse pointer to drag the point till it reaches the other control... but i guess i have to change my control's dimensions...

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see the whole code it's a bit hard to guess but try the below :

```
$( ".parent" ).droppable({
        accept: ".child",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    tolerance:'touch',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" ).appendTo(ui.Target);
                     event.preventDefault(); // or `return false;` 
        }
    });
```

Comment: doesn't help, you can see how parent 2 and 3 behaved when child was hovered between them